# Is the vector difference of two subspaces also a linear subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ and W both be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the set $V-W$, which is the set of all vectors that can be written as $x=v-w$, where $v\in V$ and $w\in W$. Is $V-W$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

This is a  problem I was assigned, and I am not sure which theorems to use to justify my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can show that if $-w\in W$ then $w\in W$ by writing $-w=-1\times w$, and then use the result that $V+W$ is a vectorial subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $F$. In order for a subset of a vector space to be a subspace, it must:

- Contain the zero vector ($0 \in V$)
- Be closed under addition ($v, w \in V \implies v+w \in V$)
- Be closed under scalar multiplication ($\lambda \in F$ and $v \in V \implies \lambda v \in V$)

So you must prove that these hold for $V-W$. The fact that these hold for $V$ and $W$ in your problem (since they're vector spaces) will prove useful.